# Angular ngx-translate getTranslation issue

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I am using ngx-translate to translate my Angular Web-app, and it seems that ngx-translate has an issue with the function `getTranslation(language)`. When it's called, it changes the current language ?temporarly? and then my component is not displayed in the right language.

```
export class InputRadioComponent extends FormComponentInput implements OnInit {
  constructor(protected formDynamicS) {
  }

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.translate.getTranslation("fr").subscribe(res => {
      this.choose["fr"] = res['form-component']['choose-answer'];
    });
    this.translate.getTranslation("en").subscribe(res => {
      this.choose["en"] = res['form-component']['choose-answer'];
    });
    this.translate.getTranslation("de").subscribe(res => {
      this.choose["de"] = res['form-component']['choose-answer'];
    });
  }
}
```

In this case, like `this.translate.getTranslation("de")` is the last call, my component is always displayed in german. I find a workaround but it's not something I want to keep on my code. Here is my workaround :

```
let languages: string[] = ["fr", "en", "de"];

languages.splice(languages.indexOf(this.translate.currentLang));
languages.push(this.translate.currentLang);

languages.forEach((language) => {
  this.translate.getTranslation(language).subscribe(res => {
    this.choose[language] = res['form-component']['choose-answer'];
  });
});
```

It allows me to keep the currentLang, because it will be the last call by `getTranslation`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same problem just now. I had to use cloneDeep (lodash method) to fix the problem.

```js
const translateDeepCopy = cloneDeep(this.translate);

translateDeepCopy.getTranslation(lang).subscribe(res => {
  
});
```

Comment: That's an horrible way to get the correct translation, but I think that's the best solution so far. As there is no good answer because this is a bug, I'll validate your answer, thanks for your solution !

Answer (score 1):

I agree, that this is a rather strange behaviour. But referring to your workaround you could have an easier solution to reset the language.

just call

```
this.translate.use('<LANGUAGE>');
```

e.g.

```
this.translate.getTranslation("de").subscribe(res => {
  this.choose["de"] = res['form-component']['choose-answer'];
  this.translate.use('en');
});
```

Comment: It's a nice idea you got here, I should warn people in my post but I already tried this, and it didn't worked. And it's not a clean code either I think, I would see if there is another way to get specific translations or another solution.. But thanks for your help buddy

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you load each translation file at startup and keep a reference in a service? It is not ideal but if your translations files are relatively small and you don't have that many languages to deal with then it may be a good trade-off.

Strangely enough, I do call getTranslation from my code and it does not change language while translate.use obviously does.

Comment: I could still read the .json file but the idea was to find a clean method to do this. I'm not currently working on this project anymore, but maybe it's something that has been fixed in an update ? I will have to check someday

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you to use Transloco for this case, it doesn't suffer from the described behavior and even easier to use for your case.

In Transloco `getTranslation` would be like:

```
const translation = this.translate.getTranslation("fr");
this.choose["fr"] = translation['form-component']['choose-answer'];
```